# Serverless with nodejs and mysql => Process exited before completing request

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm developing some functions with serverless with the nodejs template. I have a service that connects to a mysql database and retrieves some data. Everything is fine when I make the first call, but when I repeat it I receive a "Process exited before completing request" error message.
If I try that same call again, I receive data. So the service is doing right on the odd calls and it's returning the error on the even calls (funny right?). This is the code of the handler function:

```
module.exports.getAll = (event, context, done) => {
  deviceRepository.getAllDevices().then((response) => {
    done(null, { response });
  }).catch((error) => {
    done(error);
  });
};
```

and this is the code of the repository function:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const when = require('when');
const config = require('./config');

const conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: config.RDSHOST,
  user: config.RDSUSER,
  password: config.RDSPASS,
  database: config.RDSDB,
  port: config.RDSPORT
});

module.exports.getAllDevices = () => {
  const deferred = when.defer();
  conn.connect();
  conn.query('SELECT * FROM device', (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
      deferred.reject(err);
    } else {
      deferred.resolve(rows);
    }
    conn.end();
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

As you can see I use promises with the 'when' library. I call the 'done' callback in the handler, and there should be a response from the promise in every possible situation.

I can't see what is wrong with this and why is making the odd requests wrong. Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by myself...

The problem is that I was making the createConnection outside of the handler (when I declared the conn constant).

Moving the createConnection declaration inside the handler function works as expected in every call.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const when = require('when');
const config = require('./config');

module.exports.getAllDevices = () => {
  const conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: config.RDSHOST,
    user: config.RDSUSER,
    password: config.RDSPASS,
    database: config.RDSDB,
    port: config.RDSPORT
  });
  const deferred = when.defer();
  conn.connect();
  conn.query('SELECT * FROM device', (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
      deferred.reject(err);
    } else {
      deferred.resolve(rows);
    }
    conn.end();
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Great ! But I think it would be better to create only one connection and re-use it throughout your app, else you will swarm your database and lost a lot of time for each request creating connection.

Comment: Thanks @BorisCharpentier. I agree with you (that's why I created just one connection at the top of the Repository). The problem is that, as the services are "independent" they not share context, and the execution seems to be isolated. In other words, each serverless handler function is like an independent app (I don't know if someone is going to call another service which needs database connection after this one), so it seems I need to open and close the connection on each call.
That would be different on a express server or another server solution. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, if you are serverless like in a aws lambda, or anything related, you don't have a choice, else in express you would share one connection throughout your app, yes ! That's a "drawback" on serverless architecture I hadn't thought about, thanks a lot !

Comment: I thought a little more, and I think you'r creating a spof with your mysql (you can scale as much as your mysql connection pool, it can be fast http://serverfault.com/questions/599421/highest-value-of-max-connections-in-aws-rds-micro-instance) I think I would have created a service that expose mysql(a simple expressjs app) and above that a serverless architecture (or ditch mysql for dynamoDB/mongo/any micro services oriented DB). My2cents.

Comment: I researched a bit more and I found something that seems to be the right solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/36010035

I don't like the idea of expose a server (like an expressjs app) to use lambda functions through it. It would be a serverless but with a server xd. Thanks @BorisCharpentier!